# Game in python. How to make sure that people don't cheat, by modifying the script?

Tags: python

I'm creating a game on python, with pygame. It's a basic game : the user choose a username, and after playing he obtains a score. Then, his score and pseudo are send to an online database ( a google sheet). Now, I'd like to share this games with some people. But they can easily cheat by modifying the script.

For example, they could replace the line " if ... : score += 1" by "if ... : score += 100". They could also use the function create_score(score,pseudo), and directly send a fake score and pseudo to the database, without playing...

First, I tried to create an exe file, but after hours of trying, it looks like pyinstaller doesn't work well with pygame.. Do you have any other solution ?

Comment: Unless you can verify what actually happened in the game, you can't prevent people sending made up scores. Even if they don't alter your code, they could check what message is being sent and just send a fake one.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you to use pyg.exe to package it:
https://www.pygame.org/project-pyg.exe-2830-.html